# Open new Activity after click item in navigation drawer menu

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, navigation, drawer

Hello Everyone I am a beginner and just started coding in android i found a tutorial regarding, how to make navigation drawer.

Tutorial Link:- http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html

I do wanna know is there any way if i click on options in navigation drawer, a new activity will open it will be a great help for answer.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Link no more working, may need to modify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
switch (position) {
   case 1:
         Intent intent= new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
         break;
    case 2:
          ...
    default:
         break;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Im using

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_cinema) {
                Intent cinemaIntent = new Intent(this, CinemaActivity.class);
                startActivity(cinemaIntent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tv) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tvseason) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

and it's work for me :)
(It's the default android nav drawer menu)

Comment: Works for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

as new implementation you can use the fresh Design Support Library that introduced the `NavigationView` class and `DrawerLayout` pattern. Check [the release notes](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html?utm_campaign=android_update_important_bug_fixes_101515&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=blog) for more info.